# Upload image to MySQL database using mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

can someone provide me an example how to insert image using php mysqli into MySQL longblob field? and display it back using php mysqli?

here is my db table

```
IMAGE
{
    IMAGE_ID int(11)
    IMAGE_OWNER varchar(128)
    IMAGE_BLOB longblob
    IMAGE_NAME varchar(300)
    IMAGE_TYPE varchar(50)
    IMAGE_SIZE int(11)
}
```

I know how to upload it using PHP PDO, but I was wondering if I could done it using mysqli.

**NOTE:**

If you want to say "this is a bad way to store image" or "better use directory for storing image".

Before doing that, please tell me another way to make image only visible to it's uploader.

Comment: When you put the images as files in a directory thats not reach from webserver, so you can write a very little script which test you conditions and then reads the file and put the data to the customer

Comment: thank's that is a really good suggestion, but currently I don't have any directory that's unable to reach from server, currently I'm using www.freewebhostingarea.com

Comment: you can also use a directory inside the webserver and protect it with a htaccess. so nobody can get content from it only your script can do it

Comment: another good solution but webhost doesn't allow me to do `move_uploaded_file($_FILES['imgUser']['tmp_name'], '../user/img/test.jpg');` then how can I move it from the temp folder to the image directory?